# Are “Pokémon” and “Pokemon” different keywords to Google?

Tags: seo, google-search, keywords, unicode

**Does Google categorize *Pokémon* and *Pokemon* as different keywords?** I would assume most people write "Pokemon" without the ´ simbol since it is easier, though the correct way to write it is "Pokémon".

I tried searching both "Pokémon" and "Pokemon" in the Google search engine, and different results did appear so I am assuming that the Google search engine doesn't automatically assume everyone typing "Pokemon" means "Pokémon".

**Does anyone know if the Google search engine has any particular stance on how to handle similar Unicode characters?**

Comment: The "´ symbol", as you call it, is an accent, which is a particular kind of [diacritic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic). The `é` character is directly accessible from many keyboards all over the world, "easier" depends on the keyboard (yes, there is a world out there!) The character `e` is a Unicode character just as much as the character `é`, so what you call a "Unicode character" would probably be better termed a "non-ASCII character".

Comment: this is so great comparsion, me gusta.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Google knows different spelling for words (synonyms and use of accents/diacritics), it knows "Pokémon" can also be spelled like "Pokemon". That being said google will return either "Pokemon" and "Pokémon" results if searched for "Pokemon" and do the same for "Pokémon". However, it does give them a different ranking. This is based on the IP-address of the searcher and the searcher's interface language. It seems like it's best to go with the unaccented versions of the words in terms of SEO, unless you are very specific in geo-targetting and know your targets will rather use the accented version of the word instead of the unaccented version.

Reference:

- http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.nl/2006/08/how-search-results-may-differ-based-on.html
- [Do accented words affect page rank?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/19732/do-accented-words-affect-page-rank)
- https://books.google.nl/books?id=OebyMEFaNbUC&pg=PA301&lpg=PA301&dq=seo+~diacritics+~accents&source=bl&ots=T0tUFFZtJ7&sig=XALBAtrq-7WQwVEvYG_Te5wzstE&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAzgKahUKEwisyqOY-d7IAhUBkxQKHY2lA58#v=onepage&q=accented%20characters&f=false